# How to identify whether the checkbox is checked or not under specific tr?

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes in td's under tr.. What i want to do , if any one of the checkbox is checked , i need to show some activity.. How to check that scenario. Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

use `is` and `:checked` pseudo-selector

```
if ($('tr checkbox').is(:checked)) {
// do stuf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind event to your checkboxes you can do like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'tr to input:checkbox', function() {
   if ($(this).is('checked')) {
      // your logic
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know when you want to check but i have made simple example for you on change

```js
$('.checkbox input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert("input checked")
  }
  else {
  alert("input not checked")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="responsive-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="checkbox">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```